# Change the font color

Tags: html, yii2

In this line of code:

```
<b><?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Download'), ['download-file', 'id' => 'SSF']) ?></b>
```

I want to change the font color of **Download** to red by putting style inside this code. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#a()-detail)

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Download'), ['download-file', 'id' => 'SSF'], ['class' => 'myclass', 'style' => 'color: red;']) ?>
```